# Java SWT - Scaled Background Image Not Working After Compiled

Tags: java, image, shell, background, swt

This is my code

```
    shell.setFullScreen(true);
    shell.setMaximized(true);
    shell.setText("SD Cyber Cafe");
    shell.setLayout(new FormLayout());

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    Image oriImage = new Image(display, "C:\\Users\\LAPTOP-SYAMSOUL\\Desktop\\lockscreen_app\\main_bg.jpeg"); //should get from database
    //System.out.println(screenSize.width);

    Image newImage = new Image(display, oriImage.getImageData(100).scaledTo(screenSize.width, screenSize.height));
    shell.setBackgroundImage(newImage);
```

When I run the app via eclipse, it works fine...

But after I exported to `Runnable JAR` the background Image is not scaled... why??

This is what I expected:
[image]

..

..

..

But currently it appear like below: ( I don't want this):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say for sure from this code but `Toolkit` is a Swing/AWT method and should not be used with SWT. It may well be giving the wrong values.

Get the primary display size using something like:

```
Rectangle displayArea = shell.getDisplay().getPrimaryMonitor().getBounds();
```

which tells you about the main (primary) monitor or

```
Rectangle displayArea = shell.getMonitor().getBounds();
```

which tells you about the monitor on which the shell will appear (may be different if there are several monitors).